# Rotating a cube on its axis

Tags: html, css

I finally managed to build a cube but i'm unable to rotate it on its axis. In addition the rotation is not smooth. Could someone please help me to figure out how to rotate it on its axis - one time horizontally and the second vertically and so on...

Here is my cube:
https://jsfiddle.net/4b0y853r/2/

```
**Html**
<div id=container>
  <div id=card>
    <div class=front>
      1
    </div>
    <div class=right>
      2
    </div>
    <div class=top>
      3
    </div>
    <div class=left>
      4
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
      5
    </div>
    <div class=back>
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

**Css**
#container{
    margin: 160px 160px;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: perspective(1000px);
}

#card {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(-45deg);
}

#card > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.front {
  background: red;
}

.back {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -75px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.bottom {
  background: purple;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I see smoother in Firefox

Comment: I believe this only works correctly on Apple Safari™ Browser.

Comment: @ArifBurhan you believe very bad. There's no `-webkit-`  prefixes, it's probably that doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change 2 things

a) You already have transform-origin correctly set on your container, but this is dimension-less. Set it the proper dimensions

b) your face element needs also to be centered on the z axis.

The changes are commented in the snippet

```js
A();
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
function A() {
  setTimeout(function() {
   y+=180;
    document.getElementById('container').style.transform = 'rotateY(' + y + 'deg)';
    B();
  }, 1000);
}

function B() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    x+=180;
    document.getElementById('container').style.transform = 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg)';
    A();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#container{
    height: 150px;    /* added */
    width: 150px;     /* added */
    margin: 160px 160px;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: perspective(1000px);
}

#card {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateY(-45deg) rotateX(-45deg) translateZ(75px); /* modified */
}

#card > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.front {
  background: red;
}

.back {
  background: brown;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -75px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.right {
  background: blue;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: translateX(100%) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  background: green;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}

.left {
  background: yellow;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-90deg);
}

.bottom {
  background: purple;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id=card>
    <div class=front>
      1
    </div>
    <div class=right>
      2
    </div>
    <div class=top>
      3
    </div>
    <div class=left>
      4
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
      5
    </div>
    <div class=back>
      6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vals ! It looks great now =) Now i'll try to make the spinning run smoother

Comment: I see now what was the problem. I was thinking that was a smooth problem, but is the axis. Good solution

Comment: Hey @vals. Is there any mathematical logic behind the 'translateZ(75px)' that I can follow? Is it a calculated number? Why 75px?

Comment: Your cube was lying on a side. If you wnat it to be centered, you have to move it half the cube dimension, that is 150px